# Azure Devops Pipeline howto export variable dynamically in cmd.exe script

Tags: azure, variables, continuous-integration, devops, pipeline

Hi I have a small snippet to run on Azure devops.

- It is from an larger project using the "**windows-latest**"
- Runs as **script** aka cmd.exe bat

```
  steps:
  - script: |
      set ARTEFACTNAME=lorem.txt
      echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=psJobVariable;isOutput=true]%ARTEFACTNAME%
      echo "lorem ipsum dolor" > %ARTEFACTNAME%
    displayName: 'compile_windows'
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(compile_windows.psJobVariable)'
      ArtifactName: 'ci_test_windows'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
    displayName: 'publish windows'
```

The error from the publish is:

`##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\s\$(compile_windows.psJobVariable)`

means this variable is not set

I can confirm it creates the lorem.txt file with the content but ist does not create the PipeLine variable "psJobVariable" for the Publish step?
What needs to be changed to make this work?

I tried several " around the "echo ##vso[..."  line but no help.

I am expecting this variable to be set to lorem.txt

Answer (score 0):

You don't refer the output variables by using `$(myTaskDisplayName.myVar)`, instead use `$(myTaskName.myVar)`.

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: |
    set ARTEFACTNAME=lorem.txt
    echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=psJobVariable;isOutput=true]%ARTEFACTNAME%
    echo "lorem ipsum dolor" > %ARTEFACTNAME%
  displayName: 'compile_windows'
  name: 'compile_windows'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(compile_windows.psJobVariable)'
    ArtifactName: 'ci_test_windows'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  displayName: 'publish windows'
```

**EDIT - 11/12/2023**

Example of working pipeline

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. The output of the pipeline is:

`##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\s\$(compile_windows.psJobVariable)`
It seems that the variable is not resolved.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working pipeline that I tested out. Use the exact same YAML, if it still doesn't work. Edit your question and share what you changed and what error did you get.